# WP8 Center Of Map

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8

I have a map which zooms in and centers to the location of the user when the page loads. What I want to do now is allow the user to move around the map (which it can do) and when they click on a button, it saves the center coordinate (lat and long) of that location. I will need to add an image of maybe a + sign on the map to aid their accuracy.

Does anyone know how I might achieve this? I guess i'll need some sort of Overlay to plot the + sign image so that it's always in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlays are located at certain *map* coordinates, while you want to center an image in the *screen* coordinates. You can do that by simply laying out the map component and your image on top of each other:

```
<Grid Name="MapGrid">
  <maps:Map Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="64"
         VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="64"
         Source="/Assets/crosshair.png" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```